# How do you host videos and direct-link to it?

Tags: video

What type of services host videos and lets you direct link to them.  For example, images are easy enough...just find images on google images and it direct links to it, but how do you do it for videos?  Is there such a way?

Answer (score 0):

This feels like a very, very general question. I'm pretty sure you're supposed to ask something more specific.

Maybe the term you're missing is "embed." You don't just link to videos, you embed a service's video player into a website.

YouTube and Vimeo are two popular examples of websites which host video content and allow you to embed most videos in your own website or on Facebook/Twitter/MySpace or whatever. Instructions and methods of getting an embed code from different services vary, but the idea is the same. Do your own research, but YouTube would be a popular place to start.

Check out their embedding instructions: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en

Comment: nope, I'm talking about https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/unnbgkdbmsszmazgxkmr.jpg, it has .jpg at the end but how do you get the same thing with with video files

Comment: Images don't need a player like videos do, so if you intend to view them in a webpage, you need a player, hence an embed code.

To download a video, you need the author's/creator's explicit permission. Other related activity is illegal....